# Google DFP safeframe/friendlyframe Issue

Tags: iframe, google-dfp

Recently ran into some trouble with Google DFP that I'm hoping others have had.

We have a site that's served via SSL and it contains some Google DFP ad tags. Google DFP's debugging console shows no errors in the tags or our implementation of them. (i.e. the tags themselves are fine)

However, the ads are getting served via different methods. Some of the iframes get served as FriendlyFrames and some get served as SafeFrames. The SafeFrame ads appear correctly. The FriendlyFrame ads don't show up.

It appears that the FriendlyFrame ads are running afoul of some sort of browser security measure (likely because the pages are served via SSL).

I looked into this in the DFP docs but haven't found anything that explains how to solve the issue.  There is a setForceSafeFrame method available that I've tried to use but it doesn't actually seem to do anything when I try to use it:

https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletag.PassbackSlot_setForceSafeFrame

I've setup a test page demonstrating the issue here:

https://methnen.com/ad-test

There should be 5 separate ads on the page. If you get all of them refresh the page until you get at least one ad that doesn't show. The broken ads are being served as a FriendlyFrames.

Really hoping someone knows what the heck is going on.

Comment: I don't see any problems with your page. Did you manage to fix it then?
I've refreshed about 10 times and each time I see 5 ads. Also, some of these are friendly iframes and they load just fine.

Are you sure it's not a problem with one of your browser extensions?

Comment: Was just coming back to update this so people know what happened. But yes it's resolved. Turns out the Ad Ops person hadn't set things up on their end to have enough inventory to fill all of the slots and there was nothing wrong with the tagging at all. The empty FriendlyFrames are apparently what DFP serves up when it decides it doesn't have anything to fill a given slot.

Comment: Btw, I forgot to comment, but do you know that you can add the parameter "?google_force_console=1 . Google will show you a console for DFP and you should have been able to debug these kinds of issues.

Comment: Yep. We'd done that, but it left the empty containers somewhat confusing in this case. In other cases that has been a wonderfully helpful to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI and possibly helpful for anyone else who might run into this at a later date:

Turns out the Ad Ops person hadn't set things up on their end to have enough inventory to fill all of the slots and there was nothing wrong with the tagging at all. The empty FriendlyFrames are apparently what DFP serves up when it decides it doesn't have anything to fill a given slot.

Comment: We're having the exact same issue. FriendlyFrame is always showing empty. Would really appreaciate if you could share how you overcome this issue.

Comment: My answer was as descriptive as I can be. There wasn't enough inventory and there was nothing setup to serve as backup when the inventory wasn't sufficient. It was an add scheduling issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try to force render all ads in SafeFrame

```
googletag.pubads().setForceSafeFrame(true);
```

More about it here https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletag.PassbackSlot_setForceSafeFrame

Comment: I've tried to use but it doesn't actually seem to do anything as the actual problem it does find any ads to show.